# java: watch a function till given time

Tags: java, function

I like to define a time(say 3, 5 or 10 minutes) for my function to run i-e if my function does not respond-back/return anything till given I like to snatch control from that function or i interrupt that function and continue as i like. I can use any thread to achieve this as well if there is any possibility in java threading.

Comment: You can use [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Comment: You can regain control, but you won't be able to interrupt the function, unless it is explicitly written to be interruptible.

Comment: Topolnik is right, if your function is not interruptible (e.g. `while (true) { }`), there is no legal way to stop it.

Comment: [In Java: how can I make thread watch over another thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596475/in-java-how-can-i-make-thread-watch-over-another-thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly You can use [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and then you can call [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) with timeout. Note get is blocking call and it throws `TimeoutException` if wait timed out.